# Best Practices Connection String Security in config file

Tags: asp.net, .net, connection-string

What are the best practices for securely managing a connection string in a config file in production environment.
Thanks

Comment: Why the down votes? It's a perfectly good question and there are written documentation on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways to encrypt the connection string. [MSDN describes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dx0f3cf2(v=vs.85).aspx) one way. There is also an article at asp.net on the [same subject](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/data-access/advanced-data-access-scenarios/protecting-connection-strings-and-other-configuration-information-cs).

However, imho it's a hassle not worth it. Use a windows account instead of a SQL Server account and simply make sure that no unauthorized persons have access to your servers.